# Is this output normal for a capacitor filter?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, filter

I have a question regarding oscillator outputs and capacitor filters.

I'm trying to build a voltage regulator. I've already calculated and tested the transformer and rectifier, and also the filter part. But when I looked at the output waves from the oscilloscope, the output is straight. Like this:

[image]

From the photos I have seen online:

[image]

The output waves are very different, is this a normal output from the filter? Take note though that I have a very high value for the farads.

The equation I used to solve this is: 
C = (Iload  /  2) * frequency * Vpp
where Iload = 1 A, f = 1Hz, Vpp = 1V

The result is 0.5F or 500000uF.

Is it an acceptable output from the capacitor filter?

Here is my schematic so far:

[image]

Comment: Add a 1 amp load to the output.

Comment: Compute the ripple voltage for that capacitor into the actual load.

Comment: 1Hz is not realistic.  AC in most parts of the world is either 50Hz or 60Hz.

Comment: Also, I think your formula is off for the capacitor value.  Check [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122413/how-to-calculate-the-values-of-capacitors-for-5v-dc-power-supply) and compare to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the ripple on the output you must add a load in parallel with the capacitor. Add a resistor that will draw about 1A at your desired output voltage.

Also, you must adjust the timescale of your simulation so that you can see the ripples. Have your ac source start at 0.1s and simulate for just one second.